# Submission that redirects

Tags: orbeon

I don't have access to my work PC right now, but I was hoping that I can convey enough information so that some can point me in the right direction. (I'm also not sure at this point if this is an Orbeon problem to solve or a Spring MVC one).
We have a Spring MVC web application that "handles" the processing and storage of XML created by calls to a separate deployment of Orbeon.In the xform, we have a "post" submission that calls a controller method for saving the instance. We would like a "result feedback" page to be shown ("succeeded, failed with error..xxx") after the submit. If it fails the storage operation, we would this feedback page to include the error information. (We have tested using Spring MVC "flash attributes" for this, we would like to use the 'post/redirect/get' mvc pattern).

If I do this:`<xf:submission method="post" resource="/saveXform" instance="mainInstance" replace="none"> <xf:action event="xforms-submit-done"> <xf:load resource="resultpage" show="replace"/></xf:action> </xf:submission>`
the 'saveXform' controller method completes (the actual result is logged), and Orbeon loads a "resultpage", but what we would like to do is have **our** controller method actually replace the xforms page that was displayed so we can send the result data to that page: however, having the method return a view does nothing.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious about either xforms or Spring MVC. Is this possible to do? (Is it because the submission is a post that is called by Ajax, and the controller method cant do anything until the Ajax call returns?) We want our "saveXform" method to be able to display the feedback, and not Orbeon. What's the correct way to go about this? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi Francis, this is a tough one, as I don't know about the Spring MVC framework, so don't understand part of the question you are asking. Would you be able to rephrase your question in such a way that it doesn't rely on knowledge of the Spring MV framework? -Alex

Comment: After re-reading your question, I think that I figured what you were after. I posted an answer below, and of course just let me know if I'm off track, and misunderstood your question. -Alex

Comment: will be embarrassed if that's all it needs, but I'll try it as soon as I can!

Answer (score 0):

You're saying that you have a web app that stores XML coming from Orbeon Forms. I imagine that you have users filling out forms ran by Orbeon Forms, and that upon users submitting the form, you've set up Orbeon Forms to send the XML data to your web app.

You quote an `<xf:submission>`, so I assume you are writing XForms "by hand", i.e. you are not using Form Builder to create the forms. If so, all you need to do is to use a `replace="all"` on your `<xf:submission>`, this instead of the `replace="none"` you currently have. (And you don't need that action running on `xforms-submit-done` that you quoted.) With the `replace="all"`, Orbeon Forms will "just" serve the content it gets back from your web app to the browser, acting as a sort of reverse proxy.